# How to cut broadcast ip address into another variable

Tags: linux, bash, ip

How can i get the string of the ip address.
for example i enter 192.168.2.1, is there some method to cut the 2 and 1 into other string. IF not my for loop will have problem.

```
echo -n "Please enter bmc start ip to ping 192.168."
read bmcipStartaddress

echo -n "Please enter bmc end ip to ping 192.168."
read bmcipEndaddress

for((i=$bmcipStartaddress; i<=$bmcipEndaddress; i=i+2))
do
ip="192.168.$i"
echo -n "BMC IP : $ip:"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like you need two loops, don't you?

```
read -p "Please enter bmc start ip to ping 192.168." bmcipStartaddress
read -p "Please enter bmc end ip to ping 192.168." bmcipEndaddress
outerstart=${bmcipStartaddress%.*}
outerend=${bmcipEndaddress%.*}
for ((i=$outerstart; i<=$outerend; i++)); do
    if [ $i == $outerstart ]; then
        start=${bmcipStartaddress#*.}
    else
        start=0  # or 1 or 2, depending on what you want
    fi
    if [ $i == $outerend ]; then
        end=${bmcipEndaddress#*.}
    else
        end=254  # or 253 or 255, depending on what you want
    fi
    for ((j=$start; j<=$end; j=j+2)); do
        printf 'BMC IP: 192.168.%s.%s' "$i" "$j"
    done
done
```

As you can see, `${var#*.}` removes up through the first dot in `$var` and `${var%.*}` removes from the last dot through the end.